# Rails 4 plugin with my models, where do I put migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I created a plugin (gem) with my models that I'm using in two other apps.

I placed models to /lib folder and my app is working all good. But my question is where do I put future migrations? And how do I generate migrations inside the gem? Or do I have to write them manually?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question the future migrations can be stored in **/lib/db/migrate/** folder

Coming to the second part
Rails does not include any built-in support for calling migrations from plugins.But still you can run migrations by different methods

### 1.Create a Custom Rake Task

The first method is by using a rake task

Consider an example

```
namespace :db do
namespace :migrate do
description = "Migrate the database through scripts in vendor/plugins/pluginname/lib/db/migrate"
description << "and update db/schema.rb by invoking db:schema:dump."
description << "Target specific version with VERSION=x. Turn off output with VERBOSE=false."

desc description
task :pluginame => :environment do
  ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = ENV["VERBOSE"] ? ENV["VERBOSE"] == "true" : true
  ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate("vendor/plugins/pluginname/lib/db/migrate/", ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil)
  Rake::Task["db:schema:dump"].invoke if ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format == :ruby
end
```

end
end

### 2. Call Migrations directly

```
  Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "db", "migrate", "*")).each do |file|
      require file
    end
```

### 3. Migration Generator

These methods apart you can create your own migration generator.

Generating migrations has several advantages over other methods. Namely, you can allow other developers to more easily customize the migration. The flow looks like this:

- call your script/generate script and pass in whatever options they
  need
- examine the generated migration, adding/removing columns or    other
  options as necessary

Providing the generator template example of railties gem

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/migration.rb

Please Refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/plugins.html#migrations 
for more details

Comment: Thanks this looks useful. However, I'm not sure what is wrong here: `$ rake db:migrate
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for ActiveRecord::Base
/home/ondrej/code/f4e_models/lib/db/schema.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/ondrej/code/f4e_models/lib/db/schema.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ondrej/code/f4e_models/lib/f4e_models.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ondrej/code/hub_api/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ondrej/code/hub_api/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
`